# Separate rows with based on id

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to separate this data frame

```
|    date    |                filters                | filters_values |
+------------+---------------------------------------+----------------+
| 2020-04-01 | filter_float_year,filter_enum_color   | 2020, green    |
| 2020-04-03 | filter_enum_color,filter_float_milage | red, 10000     |
+------------+---------------------------------------+----------------+
```

To get such a result:

```
|    date    |       filters       | filters_values |
+------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2020-04-01 | filter_float_year   | 2020           |
| 2020-04-01 | filter_enum_color   | green          |
| 2020-04-03 | filter_enum_color   | red            |
| 2020-04-03 | filter_float_milage | 10000          |
+------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

output of dput

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18383, 18383, 18383
), class = "Date"), filters = c("filter_float_year,filter_enum_color,filter_refiners", 
"filter_float_year,filter_float_enginepower,filter_enum_condition,filter_enum_righthanddrive,filter_refiners", 
"filter_float_year,filter_float_enginesize,filter_enum_model,filter_refiners"
), filters_values = c("2019,white", "2000,100,notdamaged,2", 
"2008,2600,rexton")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: what id? where is id in the dataframe?

Comment: @RamanMishra sorry, I meant the position id. So first element of filters with the first element in filters_value etc

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2qySQMV8
Here some data as a csv

Comment: If you have read the csv file into your r workspace, then use `dput(data)` and copy/paste the output to your question.

Comment: structure(list(date = structure(c(18383, 18383, 18383
), class = "Date"), filters = c("filter_float_year,filter_enum_color,filter_refiners", 
"filter_float_year,filter_float_enginepower,filter_enum_condition,filter_enum_righthanddrive,filter_refiners", 
"filter_float_year,filter_float_enginesize,filter_enum_model,filter_refiners"
), filters_values = c("2019,white", "2000,100,notdamaged,2", 
"2008,2600,rexton")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: In your reproducible data, length of `filters` and `filters_values` are not equal. How to match their position?

Comment: You are right, check now: 
structure(list(date = structure(c(18383, 18383, 18383 ), class = "Date"), filters = c("filter_float_year,filter_enum_color", "filter_float_year,filter_float_enginepower,filter_enum_condition,filter_enum_righthanddrive", "filter_float_year,filter_float_enginesize,filter_enum_model" ), filters_values = c("2019,white", "2000,100,notdamaged,2", "2008,2600,rexton")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `separate_rows` in `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(filters, filters_values, sep = ",")

#         date                    filters filters_values
# 1 2020-05-01          filter_float_year           2019
# 2 2020-05-01          filter_enum_color          white
# 3 2020-05-01          filter_float_year           2000
# 4 2020-05-01   filter_float_enginepower            100
# 5 2020-05-01      filter_enum_condition     notdamaged
# 6 2020-05-01 filter_enum_righthanddrive              2
# 7 2020-05-01          filter_float_year           2008
# 8 2020-05-01    filter_float_enginesize           2600
# 9 2020-05-01          filter_enum_model         rexton
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18383, 18383, 18383 ), class = "Date"), filters = c("filter_float_year,filter_enum_color", "filter_float_year,filter_float_enginepower,filter_enum_condition,filter_enum_righthanddrive", "filter_float_year,filter_float_enginesize,filter_enum_model" ), filters_values = c("2019,white", "2000,100,notdamaged,2", "2008,2600,rexton")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

***Edit:*** If some rows have no common size for `filters` and `filters_values`, then you need to filter out those rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(c("filters", "filters_values"), strsplit, ",") %>%
  filter(lengths(filters) == lengths(filters_values)) %>% 
  unnest(c(filters, filters_values))
```

Comment: At some point they are not equal:
```No common size for `filters`, size 4, and `filters_values`, size 5```

Comment: @Michel That means at some rows of your data, `filters` has 4 element, and `filters_values` has 5 element. So how to match them?

Comment: I will exclude these results

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R` approach:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2020-04-01", "2020-04-03"),
                 filters = c("filter_float_year,filter_enum_color", "filter_enum_color,filter_float_milage"),
                 filters_values = c("2020, green", "red, 10000"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Solution:

Create new dataframe recycling the dates from `df` based on the number of splits in the `filters` column and filling in the other two columns from the results of `strsplit` operations:

```
dfnew <- data.frame(date = c(rep(df$date,each = length(strsplit(df$filters, ",")))),
                    filter_split = unlist(strsplit(df$filters, ",")),
                    filter_values_split = unlist(strsplit(df$filters_values, ", ")))
```

Result:

```
dfnew
        date        filter_split filter_values_split
1 2020-04-01   filter_float_year                2020
2 2020-04-01   filter_enum_color               green
3 2020-04-03   filter_enum_color                 red
4 2020-04-03 filter_float_milage               10000
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will drop entries that dont have a correspondance in the other column. Eg if you have a,b,c,d and 1,2,3 in long form you will see only a,1 - b,2 - c-3:

```
library(data.table)

d <- setDT(d)

# get number of splits
n <- max(lengths(strsplit(d$filters, ",")))
d[, (paste0("a_", 1:n)) := tstrsplit(filters, ",")]

n <- max(lengths(strsplit(d$filters_values, ",")))
d[, (paste0("b_", 1:n)) := tstrsplit(filters_values, ",")]

d[, ID := 1:.N]

dd <- melt(d, id.vars = c("ID","date"),
          measure.vars = patterns(filters = "a_",
                                  filters_values = "b_"), na.rm = T)

dd[order(ID)]
   ID       date variable                    filters filters_values
1:  1 2020-05-01        1          filter_float_year           2019
2:  1 2020-05-01        2          filter_enum_color          white
3:  2 2020-05-01        1          filter_float_year           2000
4:  2 2020-05-01        2   filter_float_enginepower            100
5:  2 2020-05-01        3      filter_enum_condition     notdamaged
6:  2 2020-05-01        4 filter_enum_righthanddrive              2
7:  3 2020-05-01        1          filter_float_year           2008
8:  3 2020-05-01        2    filter_float_enginesize           2600
9:  3 2020-05-01        3          filter_enum_model         rexton
```

Comment: The problem is that I can have far more values separated with a comma in filters :(. I cannot say even how many but more than 10 probably

Comment: Ok, I checked, the maximum number of commas is 15 so I had to create 17 columns...